# scala for loop generator - adding newline after complete second loop

Tags: java, scala

Bit confused how to add newline character after complete with inner for loop. 
Excepted output would be

```
12345678910
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

written the code in scala , but numbers are print in the same line

```
for {

    i <- 1 to 10

    j <- 1 to i

  } {
    print(s"${j}")

  }
```

excepted numbers are printing in the same line. but achieve the same output via recursively function. Any idea how can i do with for generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
for (i <- 10 to 1 by -1; j <- 1 to i) {
  if (j != i) print(j)
  else println(j)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez. ..its working

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution. No recursion required.

```
for {i <- 10 to 1 by -1} {
  for {j <- 1 to i} print(j)
  println()
}
```

Or, if you prefer a single `for` statement.

```
for {i <- 10 to 1 by -1}
  println(Range(1,i+1).mkString)
```

But, in truth, I wouldn't bother with a `for` comprehension. It's not needed.

```
Seq.tabulate(12)(Range(1,_).mkString).reverse.foreach(println)
```

Comment: thanks ..it is old way of school. any other thought in for generator